# Reading the linux utmp file without using fopen() and fread()

Tags: c, linux, file

I am trying to open the utmp file in Linux and read the contents into an array of utmp structures. After that I display the ut_user and ut_type from each structure in the array. I have this working when I open the file with `File *file` and use the `fopen()` and `fread()` functions but when I try to do the same task with just a file descriptor `int file` and the `open()` and `read()` functions I get address locations when trying to access members of the utmp structure.

So in the below program you can see I commented out three lines of code which together I could use to successfully perform the task of reading the utmp file into an array of utmp structures and print out two of their members values. But when I try doing the exact same thing with the three lines of code (denoted "new way") in place of the old way that worked I get a bunch of address locations rather than the values of `ut_user` and `ut_id`.

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <utmp.h>


    void utmpprint(struct utmp *log) {

        printf("\n ut_user: %s \n ut_type: %ld \n", log->ut_user, log->ut_type);
    }


    int main() {

        int logsize = 10;

        //FILE *file;        //Working way
        int file;            //New way

        struct utmp log[logsize];
        int i = 0;

        //file = fopen("/var/run/utmp", "rb");   //Working way
        file = open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY);  //New way

        if( file < 0 ) {  //New way
           printf("Failed to open");
           return(0);
        }

        if (file) {

                //fread(&log, sizeof(struct utmp), logsize, file);  //Working way
                read(file, &log, logsize);                          //New way

                for(i = 0; i < logsize; i++) {

                        utmpprint(&log[i]);
                }

                close(file);     //New way

        } else {
                return(0);
        }

        return(0);
    }
```

Here is some of the output for the working way:

[image]

And here is the output for the new way that is not working:

[image]

I have tried looking online for more information on this matter but I can't seem to find anything that uses the file descriptor and not `File`. I also tried changing around some of the pointers and references but that did not improve any of the results.

I am very new to C and I think I am probably using the `read()` function incorrectly in this case because I am passing a simple buffer into the read function when I think I should be somehow passing it the `utmp structure array`.

Comment: `file = file = open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY);`?  Is that a typo?  Any change when you do `file = open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY);` instead?  Also, your check for ["success"](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) should be `if (file >= 0) { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not reading enough data from the file.

```
read(file, &log, logsize);
```

should be:

```
read(file, &log, sizeof(log));
// or
read(file, &log, logsize * sizeof (struct utmp));
```

Also, in both cases, you should check the return value to see how many bytes were actually read.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you could manipulate data from the utmp file by using the `open()` system call or functions derived from `open()`, it is impractical.

You could include the "utmp.h" header in your project and use predefined functions and data structures.

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=files-utmph-file) you can find the utmp.h file documentation.

Below is some code to print the `ut_user` and `ut_type` using the utmp.h data structures and functions.

```
#include <utmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    struct utmp* data;
    char aux[50];
    data = getutent();
    //getutent() populates the data structure with information 
    while(data != NULL )
    {
        /*make sure to use strncpy 
         *because most data fiels in the utmp struct 
         *have ___nonstring___ atribute */
        strncpy(aux, data->ut_user, 32);
                aux[32] = '\0';
        printf("ut_user: %s\n", aux);
        printf("ut_type: %hi\n\n", data->ut_type);
        data = getutent();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
ut_user: reboot
ut_type: 2
    
ut_user: alc
ut_type: 7
    
ut_user: runlevel
ut_type: 1
```

Comment: Seven years later you answer! LOL kidding thank you

Comment: It was too annoying to deal with that library, I wanted to make sure nobody went through that again :))